# Can you identify this timer panel?

Tags: central-heating, timer

We have these programmable timers in our home for the Underfloor heating in the bathrooms.

There are no manufacturers markings on the panel, and they're not intuitive to program.

Anyone able to identify who makes these? knowing that I should be able to download a manual or at least a cheat sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

. . . and I found it, sorry, I've looked a dozen times but today my google-fu is strong.

It's an [Aube Th123 Series](http://www.aubetech.com/products/produitsDetails.php?noProduit=36&noLangue=2)